# How to change spec.source in cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, git, cocoapods

I have published pod on Cocoapods. It's working properly but I want to change source URL in the spec file.

Earlier my source code was at different Git repo but now I have changed to another location.

Can I update

`spec.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/path.git', :tag => 'vX.X.X' }`

without changing name of the pod and without losing versions history on cocoapods?

Comment: As per my understanding, your old version won't be affected with the new one.

Comment: Somewhere I read that each pod is tied to specific repository i.e. spec.source in the spec file and we cannot update that URL. Can we update URL? If we update it will prompt for new pod name. I want to use the same pod, don't want to lose existing pod and don't want to create new pod.

Comment: Why don't you test a dummy pod and see if this is possible or not. I think it is possible.

Comment: Okay Thanks. Will try

Comment: @nikhilgohil11 If you've tried already, is it ok to change the source?

Comment: Hi @mayankk2308 , I have used the same repository source for pod file as at that time my team didn't want to take the risk. You can try suggestion given by Inder.